# java jfilechooser disable "look in"

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I want to disable the first list named "Rechercher dans" in French or "Look in" in English

[My application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XWud.png)

I tried to do this (don't work)

`disableButton(openFile, "FileChooser.lookInLabelText");`:

with the method disableButton behind

```
public static void disableButton(final Container c, final String iconString) {
    int len = c.getComponentCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Component comp = c.getComponent(i);
        if (comp instanceof JButton) {
            JButton b = (JButton) comp;
            Icon icon = b.getIcon();
            if (icon != null
                    && icon == UIManager.getIcon(iconString)) {
                b.setEnabled(false);
            }
        } else if (comp instanceof Container) {
            disableButton((Container) comp, iconString);
        }
    }
}
```

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: Why? That is extremely hacky and will result in bad and unexpected UX.

Comment: What if you want to support another language in the future? You should identify objects by something that isn't subject to changes in state, like an ID or a GUID.

Comment: I want to set a path and the user cannot modify this one. That's the reason why i want to do that. In my program, I have already set the path to a directory (which exist, and if he don't i catch an error)

Comment: then dont use a filechooser, get the list of the files the user can chose from and present them.